# Clipping raster with vector layer using MapInfo?

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, mapinfo, clip, raster-conversion

With MapInfo 12, i would like cut my raster layer .tab with one of my vector layer.

How to do this basic task with MapInfo?

Is it possible with mapinfo to convert .tab raster table toward any standard formats (ecw, tif, etc)?

Comment: Do you really want to clip your raster file or do you just want to mask/hide part of it?

Comment: I would like mask/hide part of it. Could you tell me how to do  that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo .TAB files are merely pointers to another data source - be it native .DAT or ECW or GeoTiff or Excel etc. What is the native format the grid is in? If it's a MIG or if you have the original data used to create the grid you can use the clip tool in the thematic map options:

[image]

You can save out raster images by using the Save Window As option under the file menu, albeit with a likely heavy reduction in quality and a lot of tinkering to get the resolution right.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to cut your raster with a vector layer, I assume you want to clip it?  This is not possible in core MapInfo.  You will need an extension such as [**Discover**](http://www.pitneybowes.com/pbencom/products/location-intelligence-and-gis/encom-discover.html), [**Engage**](http://www.mapinfo.com/product/mapinfo-engage-3d/) or [**Vertical Mapper**](http://www.pitneybowes.com/pr/location-intelligence-software/mapinfo-suite/mapinfo-vertical-mapper.html).  Not only can you clip, but you can save as different raster formats.

However, there are several free solutions that will do this for you, the most popular is probably [**QGIS**](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/).  See these posts for more help:

- [Clipping raster with vector boundaries using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10117/7424)
- [Cropping raster layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24861/7424)

Answer (score 1):

From you comment I can see that you want to hide part of the raster and not need to clip the raster file.

Have a look at the Mask tool created by Egge-Jan Pollé.

You can find the tool here on the Community Download site:
http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/mask

Answer (score 1):

As well as Egge-Jan's excellent Mask tool, you can do this quite easily by selecting your vector regions in the map window then under the Map menu selecting 'Set Clip Region'. This will use your selected vector boundaries to mask the underlying raster data. You can then toggle the mask with 'Clip Region On/Off'.