# How to clip a layer file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layers, clip

I have a world imagery layer that I want to clip to a single county. I would just save as a JPEG and edit using other software, but this uses a lot of processing power if I want a high resolution. I would like to clip the image before exporting to JPEG. Is this possible?

Comment: Which software are you using?  If you are using QGIS, you can see this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/how-to-clip-a-raster-with-vector-boundaries

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: I have the same issue- trying to clip a .lyr file. I obtained the data from NCDOT and I don't think there are restrictions on the use as it applies. Any tips for working with .lyr files? Thank you.

Comment: @CarsonD Welcome to GIS SE!  Please note that you asked a question in the area reserved for answers and so it has been converted to a comment.  I recommend that you search this site, perhaps review the [Q&As tagged Clip and ArcGIS for Desktop](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+clip) and then consider posting a [New Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

To clip the Image layer, you firstly need a polygon feature class of your area of Interest.

Once You have the data, you can 'clip' the Raster Data using [Extract By Mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000). This would require a Spatial Analyst License. and would give you a raster containing the data inside your polygon.

If you require a Rectangular image, centered on your Area of Interest, you could use [Extract By Rectangle](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_by_Rectangle/009z0000002r000000/).

Comment: ERROR 000864: Input Raster: The input is not within the defined domain. ERROR 000863: Invalid GP data type.

Comment: I get these errors when I try to use my image as the input. (World Imagery.lyr). I am using a county shapefile as the extent or mask data.

Comment: Don't use the .lyr file as the input. Use the actual data.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm a novice on GIS, so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I am unable to open the file to access any kind of data. I can only open it with GIS, which kind of treats it as an image. There are no subfolders, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If this [World Imagery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9) layer is from the 'Add Data from ArcGIS Online', then you will not be able to clip or extract as indicated in the typically correct answer by @Devdatta Tengshe. There are other ways around it but will be in violation of the [Terms of Use](http://www.esri.com/legal/pdfs/mla_e204_e300/english.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use processing tool in ArcMap to clip layer, Processing menu -> clip
here clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEE9leOvtto