# Why does the Clipper tool lack the mask layer option?

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip, osx

Fairly new at QGIS, but everything's gone well so far.

I'm running QGIS version 1.8 on a Mac (OSX 10.8) and GDAL 1.10, and other GDAL tools (like Merge and Georeferencer) work just fine.

When I try to use the Clipper tool to clip a raster image using a vector shp file, I don't see the dialog options that are shown on various forums (for example, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/how-to-clip-a-raster-with-vector-boundaries)). There is no "No data value" control and under Clipping Mode I just have the option to clip to a rectangular extent. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you notice the "Mask layer" radio button in the clipper dialog windows?

Comment: No, it's not there. As I said, my options do not look like the screenshot in the link I gave, and I only have the option to clip to a rectangle, not to a mask layer.

Comment: This might be a Mac OS version issue, so please ask the maintainer of the Mac builds (kyngchaos?) directly.

Comment: I am using QGIS 1.8 Linux version (in Ubuntu 13.04), and GDAL>Extraction>clipper also only has "Extent" option - no "mask layer" option. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the version of GDALTools that shipped with the 1.8.0 branch. In fact, this issue was only recently fully fixed (at least it seems to be). On my Mac version of 1.8, which still references the 1.9.2 Kyngchaos GDAL framework install (you can have 1.9.x and 1.10.x installed at same time), the issue still occurs.

These two commits from this year address the issue (GDAL version check is now a direct numeric comparison):

https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/0c0f0883

https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/e9e1530b

There is a high likelihood that you might be able to just use those diffs to manually backport the fix to QGIS 1.8, but there is no guarantee as there might be other related commits I missed.

Unfortunately, you can not just download the latest GDALTools plugin and replace the one that shipped with 1.8 as there have been significant changes that limit the latest plugin to only running under QGIS >= 1.9.

My recommendation: use [the latest nightly build for Mac](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#421-Nightly-Builds) instead of 1.8 for the latest features in data source manipulation functionality. You can have both the nightly *and* 1.8 running on your Mac at the same time (they use different preference files), As long as you do not overwrite your 1.8 project with one saved from the nightly, you can utilize the nightly's data source manipulation functionality, then load the results into your 1.8 project.