# Tilemill: Render a raster only where a shape layer is underneath

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I'd like to mask a raster to only those areas, where there is a shape layer underneath. To be more precise: I have a land layer and a hillshading on top and I only want my hillshading to appear on top of the land, not it the water areas.

I tried around with different `comp-ops` but i didn't get what I want.

The result I'd like is see the land shape (it's color) underneath and the raster only visible on top where there is a land layer underneath.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Can you preprocess the raster? Lets say with QGis like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/how-to-clip-a-raster-with-vector-boundaries

Comment: I just tried cutting it using `gdal` BUT... my cut-shapefile are all the land-polygons of the earth (from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons) and when I start my `gdalwarp` it starts producing a suuuuper large file. My input file is like 30MB but soon the cut one is more that a couple of GB... Is there a way to tell `gdal` not to do that?

Comment: I dont know gdalwarp very good, so I propose you create a new question for this problem.