# Calculate average value of a raster, that is clipped by multiple polygons?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, zonal-statistics, qgis-2.12

I have a raster of coherence value (SAR interferometry) and a land use shape. I wish to calculate mean coherence value for those areas with a specific land use. I split land use shape into specific classes that I am interested in. So now I have a shapefile of urban areas (multiple polygons) and I wish to know average coherence in all urban areas together.

When I use Zonal Statistics, I only get average value for raster for each polygon separately, but I wish to know average pixel value for all urban areas together. Are there any plugins that I could use? Or am I missing something else?

I am using QGIS 2.12.0.

Comment: Maybe you should union your polygons (one multipart feature) and use that.

Comment: @Vince - You should post your comment as an answer =)

Comment: I'm not a QGISer.  Feel free to write it up if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipping raster with vector boundaries using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/clipping-raster-with-vector-boundaries-using-qgis)