# Clipping Raster Dataset in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, arcgis-10.4

I have a raster image that I need to clip at the southern boundary of a vector dataset. Using the clip tool does not give me that option.

I am using ArcMap 10.4

Is there an option to do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clip a raster with vector boundaries?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/how-to-clip-a-raster-with-vector-boundaries)

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip

In that tool you can select mask (vector layer) to clip raster

Comment: In addition to this answer, here is a page that describes the same and more methods to accomplish this: http://gisgeography.com/clip-rasters-arcgis-polygon-boundary/

Comment: I am able to clip the raster in that way both by using the extract by mask and the method above but I want the southern extent of the image, the portion below the shapefile boundary. Is there a way to cut the raster image?

Comment: @nmichelg You can try make new mask (simple rectangle) for your southern part of the raster and then clip raster with that mask.