# Using QGIS With WebODM

Tags: qgis, opendronemap

In summary, I have a tiff file created in WebODM which has irregular borders.

I want to accomplish two things:

1. I want to crop it into a neat rectangle
2. I want it to have a scale so I assume I need to drop it into QGIS somehow to achieve this.  However, I cannot crop it in PS because it will lose its geotagging data.  I just need specific directions, steps how to accomplish both tasks.

I am new to mapping with a drone.

I created my first map with WebODM.  I want to be able to generate a map with an accurate scale that may be printed. The map came out in an irregular manner.  I was able to crop it to a neat rectangle in PS.  DroneDeploy allows you to crop prior to generating a pdf 11 X 17 pdf map.

Is it possible to use the cropped tiff which was generated by WebODM and put it into QGIS and wind up with a pdf or otherwise printable map with a scale?

Comment: See this post about clipping a raster with a polygon:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/clipping-raster-with-vector-boundaries-using-qgis.  If you are unsure how to create that polygon see this tutorial for help:  https://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/guides_vectorlayerqgis.html

Comment: And for creating the final map with a scale see here:  https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html

Comment: You mention "PS" twice.  What is that?

Comment: PS - Photoshop?